# MySQL ignores max_connections

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

MySQL 8.0.18 running on Windows Server 2019 Standard ignores partly my my.cnf/my.ini it reads perfectly datadir and default_authentication_plugin, but NOT max_connections. It keeps the default value of 151 despite that max_connections is defined with a higher number eg. 500.

my.cnf/my.ini:

```
[mysqld] 
max_connections = 500 
default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password 
datadir=X:\DummyFolder\MySQL\Data
```

I have no problem in changing this with the statement : `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 500;`

Anyone with an idea about this ?

Thanks in advance

**MY SOLUTION:** Found the one my.ini which wasn't updated to new defaults, thanks to nbk hints in his comment

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the content of the seven configuration files located at the paths listed in the table 4.1 as seen on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html#option-files-windows. Also run `mysqld --verbose --help` and look for the output "Default options are read from the following files in the given order" at the top. Add the printed line after that to your question as well. And check the value of `max_connections` inside the output of `mysqld --verbose --help`.

Comment: there are also a limits how many threads a process have and you need also resources per connection, that is mostly dependent on harware and version of the server.

Answer (score 0):

**MY SOLUTION:** Found the one my.ini which wasn't updated to new defaults, thanks to Progman and nbk hints in his comment